# Searching my answers

Tags: feature-request, answers

At this point, I have answered quite a few questions on physics.SE, and it would be very helpful to have the ability to search them.  Is there a way to restrict the physics.SE native search to only my answers?  If not, has adding such functionality been considered thus far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, just include `user:me` in your search query. You can also use something like `user:19976` to restrict the results to any particular user's posts, where `19976` should be replaced by the ID of the user.

If you want to restrict your search to only answers (as opposed to questions and answers), you can also include `is:answer`.

There are several other search operators that you can see by doing a search and looking at the right side of the results page for "Advanced Search Tips". (Or see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/searching).)

Comment: Great thanks David.

Comment: What if you don't know the user's id? Searching `user:Dimension10`, for example, doesn't seem to work .

Comment: @Dimension10 You can easily find the user ID by looking at the URL for their profile page. For example yours is `http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/23119/dimension10` and so your user ID is `23119`. You can't do this search by user name (in part because user names are not unique).

Comment: @DavidZ: I know that, but I meant like, without checking the url . It's impossible , right ? .

Comment: @Dimension10: The user ID is not shown anywhere other than in URLs, if that's what you're asking.